# NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration error message when trying to load a Configuration:

Tags: java, swing, maven

I have added the following dependency: `hibernate-core,hibernate-commons-annotations`, `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api`, `hibernate-entitymanager`, `hibernate-validator`.
I am getting the following exception while running jar:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>       org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:264)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:332)

pom.xml as below:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        com.install
        install
        0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

```
<artifactId>installer</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Installer</name>
<description>Installer main</description>

<properties>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quickfixj</groupId>
        <artifactId>quickfixj-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.installer</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Have you added all depedencies to the classpath?

Comment: i have added dependency in pom.xml file

Comment: Please post your pom.xml

Comment: Also after adding your dependencies did you do a Maven>update project to download the dependencies

Comment: yes i did that.my project is working properly from sts.but when i build jar then its giving  me the above mentioned error

Comment: if you dl your jars from maven repository. You'll able to build your jar. So with this error. You have a class not found which is `org.hibernate.cfg.configuration` and this class is present in all of the jars of hibernate : core ... So maybe you don't have the right configuration so the wrong version of hibernate. Show us your pom.xml maybe we can find a solution

Comment: @SanchitaSonawane: Are you sure your jar packages all the dependent jar as well?

Comment: @RaunakAgarwal : yes i have added all the dependencies as per program requirement.Kindly refer the above attached pom file.

Comment: Can you pleas verify that the jar that you have has all the required files in it